# Time taken by function in C. Getting strange values

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have a code where I call libcurl api. When doing load testing, the performance of the code worsens. I did some check to see the bottlenecks and from my understanding, I got strange results.

The actual call to `curl_easy_perform()` takes few microseconds while the function which calls this reports the time taken as 5000 seconds (earlier it was showing 10-20 seconds which looked realistic, but now don't know what happened.).

Below are the codes:

**getresource method ( this calls the fn which calls curl api)**

```
int getResource(const db_key_t * _k, const db_val_t * _v, const int _n, db_res_t ** _r, const char *_rt, char *_u1, char *_u2)
{

char *url = (char *) pkg_malloc(MAX_URL_LEN);

if (url == NULL) 
{
    LM_ERR("No more pkg memory left");
    return -1;
}
if (create_url(_k, _v, _n, url, _rt, _u1, _u2) < 0)
{
    LM_ERR("Failed to process request. URL creation failed.\n");
    pkg_free(url);
    return -1;
}
int status = 0;
struct json_response re;
struct json_response *jresponse = &re;

jresponse->payload = (char *) malloc(1);

if (!jresponse->payload)
    return -1;

jresponse->size = 0;

/*t = clock();
status = curl_get(url, &jresponse);
t = clock() - t;
double time_taken = ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  // in seconds
*/
clock_t t1 = clock();
LM_WARN("Time value t1: %d",t1);

status = curl_get(url, &jresponse);

clock_t t2 = clock();
LM_WARN("Time value t2: %d",t2);
double time_taken = ((double)(t2-t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

LM_WARN(" curl_get took %f seconds \n", time_taken);

int return_status = 0;

if (status == 200)      // returned results
{
    return_status = parse_json_to_result(jresponse->payload, _r);
} 
else if (status != 404) // no results, return_status = 0
{
    return_status = -1;
}

pkg_free(url);
if (jresponse->payload)
free(jresponse->payload);
LM_DBG("************parse_status: %d", return_status);
return return_status;
}
```

**curl_get (this calls curl api)**

```
int curl_get(const char* url, struct json_response **result) {
    t = clock();
    CURLcode res;
    int http_code = 0;
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    if (result != NULL) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void ** )result);
    }       
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);  
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    curl_slist_free_all (headers);
    curl_easy_reset (curl);
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

    LM_WARN(" Main call took %f seconds \n", time_taken);
    return http_code;
}
```

**And below is the log:**

```
curl_get:  main call  took 0.000220 seconds //calls the web url
getResource:  curl_get took 5778 seconds //this called curl_get
pres_search_db:  getResource took 15.482565 seconds // this calls getresource
```

Please help me understand whats going on.

**EDIT**
Variable **t** is declared as global in individual C files and all functions mentioned here are part of different .c files.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix the messy indention if you expect others to read this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see t is a global variable.

Then you are overwriting its value in `curl_get` function.

When code return from `curl_get` the  value of `t` is the elapsed time of `curl_get` execution, that is far away from the actual `clock()` return value.

**EDIT**

At the end the problem was the declaration of `t`.

In OP case there was a different file for each posted function.
In each file OP declared a `t` variable. 
This does not mean that each variable scope is local to the file where it belongs to.

Omitting `static` from a declaration means implicit `extern` linkage.

[Nutshell](https://books.google.it/books?id=OwMsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT266&lpg=PT266&dq=The+compiler+treats+function+declarations+without+a+storage+class&source=bl&ots=agC8kA9SCw&sig=81bxBAR6rBeNzUGMvgQfYksF_a8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV8ISu--DKAhXCdw8KHYGyD1oQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=The%20compiler%20treats%20function%20declarations%20without%20a%20storage%20class&f=false)

> The compiler treats function declarations without a storage class specifier as if they included the specifier extern. Similarly, any object identifiers that you declare outside all functions and without a storage class specifier have external linkage.

Comment: All three functions are part of different .c files.

Comment: @user3275095 The question is: where and how is `t` declared? I suspect `t` is declared into one c file and the `extern` on the others.

Comment: No, its declared as global variable in individual C file.

Comment: @user3275095 Try `printf("%d\n", t)` before and after `curl_get` call inside `getResource` and see what is the value. I think/hope that you are not waiting 5778 seconds really...

Comment: @user3275095 BTW, to make the story short, you probably declared t as non static. Use static keyword to make sure variable has no implicit extern linkage.

Comment: I was about to do the same. The test lasts for 200 secs :).

Comment: Yes, it's non-static. I'll make it static.

Comment: No changes. I declared t as static and for this specific function created 2 local variables t1 and t2. Below are results:
`getResource: Time value t1: 6403`
`curl_get:  main call  took 0.000242 seconds `
`getResource: Time value t2: 6695`
`getResource:  curl_get took 0.000292 seconds'

Comment: @user3275095 Could you post the new code? How does getResource really takes?

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read the logs and it looks fine. I think it's because of making the value as static. I have updated the code. From the above comment-  `getResource: curl_get took 0.000292 seconds`. But why this was happening for this particular call always!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overwriting your measurement variable t used in getResource when you enter curl_get. You then don't get a proper subtraction when you do clock() - t.

Make your individual timer declarations local and you shouldn't have these interference problems. Also please format your code properly so it is easier to read.

Comment: All three functions are part of different .c files and sorry about formatting, will correct it.